# ClickOnce update notification message

Tags: c#, clickonce

Is there a way, using ClickOnce, that I can create a message to all active users in my application that a new version has been released and that they need to restart the program to connect to the new version?

Comment: Would you be a bit more precise please? Do you mean a message box? What does "connect to the new version" mean?

Comment: Apologies. When a new version is published to the shared server, I would like a MessageBox displayed alerting the users that there is a new version published and that they need to restart the application in order to download the new version of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way to push update notifications to your application, but you can get your application to poll for updates by using the `ApplicationDeployment` class (in System.Deployment.Application, [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

e.g.

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed) {
    ApplicationDeployment current = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
    if (current.CheckForUpdate()) {
        // display notification to user
    }
}
```

Although, if you're polling a remote server, you will probably want to use the non-blocking `CheckForUpdateAsync` method and handle the `CheckForUpdateCompleted` event. That way, the user won't be interrupted during the update check.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in VS now, but I'm running into the issue that IsNetworkDeployed is stating that it does not exist. I have the 'using System.Deployment.Application;'

Comment: You have to add a reference to the System.Deployment assembly (not included in C# projects by default)

Comment: I'm teaching my self c# by doing this project so apologies for the questions. On my main form at the top, I do have the 'using System.Deployment.Application;' Is that what you are referencing to me needing to reference 'System.Deployment'?

Comment: No, you have to right-click on 'References' under your project in the Solution Explorer and choose 'Add Reference...', then locate System.Deployment, check the box and click OK.

Comment: Sorry it took me a bit to give you the answer. I wanted to make sure I could figure it out. Thank you.